# How to increase /boot partition size when installing Ubuntu 14.04 using the "use entire disk and set up encrypted LVM" option?

Tags: boot, partitioning, lvm

How to edit the size of the /boot partition when installing Ubuntu?
Using the guided partitioning option "use the entire disk and set up encrypted LVM" results is a /boot partition which is only 236MB.

Comment: AFAIK, it can't be done via that option; you should consider using the "Something Else" option instead, as described [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/343268/how-to-use-manual-partitioning-during-installation) (among many other places). FWIW, [this bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1357093) identifies a too-small `/boot` partition as a problem. If you agree, please click the link that identifies you as being affected, and perhaps add a comment.

Answer (score 3):

Guided partition sizes are specified in `/lib/partman/recipes[-arch]/*`. The file format is here: http://ftp.dc.volia.com/pub/debian/preseed/partman-auto-recipe.txt

To increase the `/boot` size, change the maximum size (third number) in the boot section of the default recipe: `sudo nano /lib/partman/recipes/30atomic`

```
...

128 512 256 ext2
    ...
    mountpoint{ /boot } .

 ....
```

Change the 256 to a something bigger and save. Then, start the installer and use the guided option.

Answer (score 0):

Use manual partitioning and try the steps I outline in [this solution](https://askubuntu.com/a/893906/606758). The process I use is for Ubuntu 16.04.2 though. With manual partitioning, I was able to create a boot partition 1GB in size with no problem. As an added benefit, you can also create additional logical volumes for /home or any other partition you might want to keep separate.