# MSI GE66-Raider-10SF Ubuntu Support

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, nvidia, 20.04

Just got a brand new MSI GE66 Raider and after more than 10hrs straight of research I finally decided to ask a question here.
So the laptop came with Windows 10 which works flawlessly, but when installing Ubuntu 20.04:

- Some of graphic drivers are not working (can't use two screens)
- Bluetooth works only intermittently
- **Most importantly** WiFi never works. I can only access internet through USB Tethering

First I would like to know if the fact that the following page shows no drivers for Ubuntu is reason enough to think that Ubuntu is just not supported for the laptop
**https://latam.msi.com/Laptop/support/GE66-Raider-10SF**

Secondly a list of all the things I tried and outputs of commonly requested commands

**Trying to find a given controller and download corresponding drivers**

```
lspci


00:1b.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCI Express Root Port #17 (rev f0)
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCI Express Root Port #9 (rev f0)
00:1d.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 06b4 (rev f0)
00:1d.6 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 06b6 (rev f0)
00:1d.7 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 06b7 (rev f0)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Comet Lake LPC Controller
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH SMBus Controller
00:1f.5 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH SPI Controller
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation Device 249d (rev a1)
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation Device 228b (rev a1)
02:00.0 USB controller: ASMedia Technology Inc. Device 3242
03:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd NVMe SSD Controller SM981/PM981/PM983
04:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Device 2725 (rev 1a)
05:00.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Device 3101 (rev 03)
06:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS525A PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
```

///

```
sudo lshw -C network

  *-network UNCLAIMED       
       description: Network controller
       product: Intel Corporation
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
       version: 1a
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:c4500000-c4503fff
```

**Tried downgrading the kernel**

**Installing an earlier version of Ubuntu**

**Reinstalled several times with Secure Boot OFF, Fast Boot OFF**

And many many many more.

Any help would be much appreciated! :D

Comment: Please edit to include results from terminal for `lspci -nnk | grep -iA3 net; dmesg | grep iwl`

Comment: Issues often common by brand and if Intel or AMD. Have you updated UEFI and SSD firmware? https://askubuntu.com/questions/1197414/dual-booting-windows-10-and-ubuntu-on-separate-ssds?noredirect=1#comment2008840_1197414 & https://askubuntu.com/questions/1061109/dual-boot-windows-10-cannot-boot-latest-ubuntu-but-only-older-versions
MSI GE63 Update UEFI then acpi=off not required
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1059029/18-04lts-msi-ge63-boot-issues & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1038637/how-to-install-ubuntu-on-msi-ge63-without-acpi-off

Comment: Were you able to fix the issues? Did you try Ubuntu 21.10? (Just browsing for a new laptop and this might be a good one... if everything works properly)

Comment: This computer is a real mess. I agree.

Answer (score 2):

I experienced similar issues when installing Ubuntu 20.04 on my MSI GE66.
I was able to solve a few of the problems.

WIFI issue [solved]: https://askubuntu.com/a/1324339/1029809

Bluetooth issue [unsolved]: [Bluetooth rapidly toggling on and off on MSI GE66 laptop running Ubuntu 20.10, using 100% of CPU](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1324530/bluetooth-rapidly-toggling-on-and-off-on-msi-ge66-laptop-running-ubuntu-20-10-u)

Multiple displays: You need to install the NVIDIA drivers to support external displays. You can do that by running: `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall`. If that doesn't work for you, then you'll need to specify the drivers you want to install: `sudo apt install nvidia-driver-xxx`.

Answer (score 0):

date: 10/12/2021, 10 in December 2021

***sorry for my bad grammar and spelling I am dyslectic***

just want to share my attempt to solve this problem for 20 days.

I have MSI GE-66 11UG means I have the wifi adapter AX Intel Corporation Wi-Fi 6 AX210/AX211/AX411. in the WIFI settings "NO WIFI ADAPTER FOUND", and sometimes my mouse ped does not work.
I am sharing my solution for that.

I am not sure what is exactly the minimal steps to do it but I will just share with you all the steps that I did to solve it.

you need the Ubuntu 21.04 and kernel 5.11.0-41-generic, lunch some gits.

**the solution step by step**

0)check your kernel and Ubuntu version by putting these lines in the terminal:
for Ubuntu version run in the terminal:

```
lsb_release -a
```

excepted output if you have the right Ubuntu version:
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 21.04
Release:    21.04
Codename:   hirsute
**if it as excepted skip step 1**

for kernel version run in the terminal:

```
uname -r
```

the excepted result if you have the right kernel version:
5.11.0-41-generic
**if it is as excepted skip step 2 ******By the way you may skip step 2 with another kernel from 5.11. (something) but it would defiantly doesn't work in 5.12. (something)**

1. for the update to Ubuntu 21.04:
   I follow https://www.how2shout.com/linux/upgrade-ubuntu-20-04-to-ubuntu-21-04-using-terminal-or-gui
2. get yourself the kernel 5.11.0-41-generic:
   in the terminal run this:

`sudo apt-get update`

​`sudo apt-get upgrade`

`sudo apt-get install update-manager-core`

`cd /tmp`

`wget -c https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.11/amd64/linux-headers-5.11.0-051100-generic_5.11.0-051100.202102142330_amd64.deb`

`wget -c https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.11/amd64/linux-headers-5.11.0-051100_5.11.0-051100.202102142330_all.deb`

`wget -c https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.11/amd64/linux-image-unsigned-5.11.0-051100-generic_5.11.0-051100.202102142330_amd64.deb`

`wget -c https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.11/amd64/linux-modules-5.11.0-051100-generic_5.11.0-051100.202102142330_amd64.deb`

`sudo dpkg -i *.deb`

`sudo reboot`

while you are in reboot be aware that you might need to choose on advance booting option and pick manually your 5.11 kernel because sometimes the machine choose automatically other kernels

after the reboot assert that you are in the right versions as mentioned in step 0 !!!!!

3. run this in the terminal:

`sudo apt update`

`sudo apt-get install -y git`

`sudo apt-get install -y build-essential`

`git clone git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git`

`cd linux-firmware`

`sudo cp iwlwifi-* /lib/firmware/`

`cd ..`

`git clone https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/iwlwifi/backport-iwlwifi.git`

`cd backport-iwlwifi`

`make defconfig-iwlwifi-public`

`make -j4`

`sudo make install`

`sudo update-initramfs -u`

`sudo reboot`

the terminal commands for step 3 are taken from here: [No WiFi Adapter Found with fresh Ubuntu 20.04 install on MSI GE66 Laptop, and other strange behavior](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1324314/no-wifi-adapter-found-with-fresh-ubuntu-20-04-install-on-msi-ge66-laptop-and-ot)

**if it works for you, great!!!!**

**if not continue for these additional steps:**

4. run this in the terminal:

`sudo mv /usr/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0.pnvm  /usr/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0.bak`

`sudo reboot`

if it not working continue for these additional steps:

5)in this intel site: https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000005511/wireless.html

download the "Intel® Wi-Fi 6 AX210 160MHz" firmware
then extract it by right click on it and clicking EXTRACT HERE
then double click on the extracted folder and open the folder in the terminal
then write this in the terminal(make sure you are inside the extracted folder)

`cp iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0-59.ucode /lib/firmware/`

`sudo reboot`

after all this process your computer wifi adapter, and mouse ped should be detected by Ubuntu
good luck!

for those who also have a problem with your GPU driver follow https://phoenixnap.com/kb/install-nvidia-drivers-ubuntu
you will need to choose "nvidia driver metapeckage from nvidia-driver-470" via using "Install Nvidia Driver Using GUI" part in the link