# No WiFi Adapter Found with fresh Ubuntu 20.04 install on MSI GE66 Laptop, and other strange behavior

Tags: drivers, wireless, 20.04, network-manager

I installed a fresh Ubuntu 20.04.2 image to my MSI GE66 laptop.
When I go to `Settings > Wi-Fi` it says "No Wi-Fi Adapter Found".

Additionally, there appears to be other strange glitchy behavior going on, but I created a [different question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1324316/strange-glitchy-behavior-in-ubuntu-20-04-bluetooth-toggling-on-and-off) regarding that.

Running `sudo lshw -C network` outputs the following:

```
  *-network UNCLAIMED       
       description: Network controller
       product: Intel Corporation
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
       version: 1a
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:c4500000-c4503fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: Intel Corporation
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:05:00.0
       logical name: enp5s0
       version: 03
       serial: 2c:f0:5d:b4:bb:26
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi msix pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=igc driverversion=0.0.1-k duplex=full ip=10.216.156.136 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:18 memory:c4200000-c42fffff memory:c4300000-c4303fff
```

The output of `lspci` is:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Device 9b44 (rev 02)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor PCIe Controller (x16) (rev 02)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation UHD Graphics (rev 05)
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Thermal Subsystem (rev 02)
00:12.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH Thermal Controller
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Comet Lake USB 3.1 xHCI Host Controller
00:14.2 RAM memory: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH Shared SRAM
00:15.0 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH Serial IO I2C Controller #0
00:15.2 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH Serial IO I2C Controller #2
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Comet Lake HECI Controller
00:1b.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCI Express Root Port #17 (rev f0)
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCI Express Root Port #9 (rev f0)
00:1d.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 06b4 (rev f0)
00:1d.6 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 06b6 (rev f0)
00:1d.7 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 06b7 (rev f0)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Comet Lake LPC Controller
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH cAVS
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH SMBus Controller
00:1f.5 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH SPI Controller
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation Device 249c (rev a1)
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation Device 228b (rev a1)
02:00.0 USB controller: ASMedia Technology Inc. Device 3242
03:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Sandisk Corp Device 5006
04:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Device 2725 (rev 1a)
05:00.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Device 3101 (rev 03)
06:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS525A PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
```

Here is what I've tried to do to fix the problem:

First I disabled secure boot in BIOS before I installed Ubuntu 20.04 b/c I've heard that can sometimes cause issues.

Next, I ran the following commands followed by a reboot:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall bcmwl-kernel-source
```

That didn't do the trick. I'm not sure what else to try from here, I don't have much experience solving problems like this.

Comment: Not an answer, but the MSI site says you have a "Killer AX Wifi" which I assume is the [Killer AX1650](https://support.killernetworking.com/knowledge-base/killer-ax1650-in-debian-ubuntu-16-04/) - this link points you at a place where you might find instructions to backport a network driver...

Comment: Thank you @CharlesGreen that did the trick!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Thank you @Charles Green for the answer.
For those facing the same issue, this is how you'd go about solving it.

The full instructions are posted [here](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000058909/wireless/intel-wireless-products.html)

Basically you need to install the drivers for the Killer AX1650 card.
Simply running these commands did **not** work:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:canonical-hwe-team/backport-iwlwifi
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install backport-iwlwifi-dkms
sudo reboot
```

Instead, what worked for me is running the following commands:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt-get install -y git
sudo apt-get install -y build-essential

git clone --depth 1 git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git
cd linux-firmware
sudo cp iwlwifi-* /lib/firmware/
cd ..

git clone --depth 1 https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/iwlwifi/backport-iwlwifi.git
cd backport-iwlwifi
make defconfig-iwlwifi-public
make -j4
sudo make install
 
sudo update-initramfs -u
sudo reboot
```

Comment: I'm glad to hear that worked out for you - make sure to revisit this tomorrow, and mork your question answered!

Comment: GS66 ppa:canonical-hwe-team/backport-iwlwifi - worked for me + kernel 5.12.6

Comment: **Important: Doesn't work when SecureBoot enabled!** Disable it in bios

Comment: How would you download a package when there's no Wifi or internet? I'm stuck here.

Comment: works for me. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 20.04
kernel 5.12.16 compiled from sources (because libc6)
all working from the box, no need for backport

Answer (score 0):

For me was helpful this steps:

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade -y 
sudo apt install mainline
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:cappelikan/ppa
```

Tab the Super key and search "mainline", then install the latest version of kernel(for me helps 5.13.4)
Download the latest linux-firmware:

```
wget http://kr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux-firmware/linux-firmware_1.199_all.deb
```

Install it:

```
sudo dpkg -i linux-firmware_1.199_all.deb
```

That is all. Reboot and enjoy with your wifi.