# Recurrent no wifi adapter found + no bluetooth on MSI GS66 Stealth 10UG-035ES

Tags: drivers, wireless, 20.04, msi

First of all, I'm fully aware that similar questions have been answered in other places, but I have follow-up questions and other problems coming from this same question, that I have not seen answered anywhere.

The MSI GS66 Stealth 10UG-035ES has a Killer Wi-Fi 6 AX1650i (2*2 ax) + BT5 which does not work by default on Ubuntu 20.04.

Following the steps from the answer given by @cyrusbehr [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1324314/no-wifi-adapter-found-with-fresh-ubuntu-20-04-install-on-msi-ge66-laptop-and-ot/1324339#1324339?newreg=a11423b59df341bc89c29e1eb5123bce), I was able to make wifi work using iwlwifi backport. But I still have a few issues:

1. After booting on windows 10 it stops working again, and I need to execute `sudo update-initramfs -u` and restart, to get wifi working again. I do not have secure boot enabled, and now (after @Jeremy31 comment) I also don't have Windows hybrid shutdown enabled.
2. Bluetooth is still not working
3. The killer AX1650 card is actually not listed when executing ´sudo lshw -C network´

```
  *-network:0               
       descripción: Interfaz inalámbrica
       producto: Cannon Point-LP CNVi [Wireless-AC]
       fabricante: Intel Corporation
       id físico: 14.3
       información del bus: pci@0000:00:14.3
       nombre lógico: wlp0s20f3
       versión: 11
       serie: 08:d2:3e:02:a3:2d
       anchura: 64 bits
       reloj: 33MHz
       capacidades: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuración: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=5.8.0-48-generic firmware=46.6bf1df06.0 9000-pu-b0-jf-b0- ip=192.168.1.128 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       recursos: irq:16 memoria:f1130000-f1133fff
  *-network:1
       descripción: Ethernet interface
       producto: Ethernet Connection (6) I219-V
       fabricante: Intel Corporation
       id físico: 1f.6
       información del bus: pci@0000:00:1f.6
       nombre lógico: enp0s31f6
       versión: 11
       serie: f8:0d:ac:47:83:53
       capacidad: 1Gbit/s
       anchura: 32 bits
       reloj: 33MHz
       capacidades: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuración: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=3.2.6-k firmware=0.5-4 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       recursos: irq:124 memoria:f1100000-f111ffff
```

In case it is useful, the output of `lspci` is:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Coffee Lake HOST and DRAM Controller (rev 0c)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation UHD Graphics 620 (Whiskey Lake) (rev 02)
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Thermal Subsystem (rev 0c)
00:12.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP Thermal Controller (rev 11)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP USB 3.1 xHCI Controller (rev 11)
00:14.2 RAM memory: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP Shared SRAM (rev 11)
00:14.3 Network controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP CNVi [Wireless-AC] (rev 11)
00:14.5 SD Host controller: Intel Corporation BayHubTech Integrated SD controller (rev 11)
00:15.0 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #0 (rev 11)
00:15.1 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #1 (rev 11)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP MEI Controller #1 (rev 11)
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP SATA Controller [AHCI Mode] (rev 11)
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #13 (rev f1)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP LPC Controller (rev 11)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP High Definition Audio Controller (rev 11)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP SMBus Controller (rev 11)
00:1f.5 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP SPI Controller (rev 11)
00:1f.6 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection (6) I219-V (rev 11)
01:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd Device a809
```

Is there any way in which 1) I can have a working satable wifi on ubuntu 20.04 and 2) perhaps having Ubuntu recognizing the bluetooth controller?

Thanks you for your time!

Comment: Is the Windows hybrid shutdown disabled?

Comment: No, I just disabled it. But Wifi still does not work after booting on windows 10 (tested several times).

Comment: Hi @Tialis did you find a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

I have this same issue on my pc, or I did. This is prominent all across every distro for me. You need to be on kernel 5.13, the update fixes Bluetooth, but Bluetooth can break after a restart, a way to prevent Bluetooth from breaking again is by disabling Bluetooth before restarting. You could do this manually or adding aliases in `~/bash.bashrc`, if this still doesn't fix it, reset the cmos. I know its difficult to open up this model, but it can be done. Afterwards run `git clone https://github.com/YoyPa/isw` in terminal, then uninstall it. i think it has the wifi drivers, idk, then just restart and it should be working. Atleast this worked for me. I have a 10ug-219
(rip grammar despite english being my first language)