# 6E AX210 PCIE WiFi Card not working on ubuntu 20.04, 5.11 kernel

Tags: networking, drivers, 20.04, kernel

WiFi is not working. Not sure how to fix it. I had same WiFi chip on my older PC where it worked by disabling fast boot. I did disable fast boot but no luck. I've done update.

How to fix it?

Some commands and output:

```
$uname -r
5.11.0-46-generic

$ lsmod | grep iwlwifi
iwlwifi               372736  1 iwlmvm
cfg80211              888832  3 iwlmvm,iwlwifi,mac80211
    
$ ls /sys/class/net
enp3s0  lo

$cat /etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml
# Let NetworkManager manage all devices on this system
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager


$ inxi -Fxz
....
Network:   Device-1: Intel vendor: Micro-Star MSI driver: igc v: kernel port: 5000 bus ID: 03:00.0 
           IF: enp3s0 state: up speed: 1000 Mbps duplex: full mac: <filter> 
           Device-2: Intel driver: iwlwifi v: kernel port: 5000 bus ID: 04:00.0 
...


$ sudo dmesg | grep iwl
[    6.394823] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    6.403106] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: api flags index 2 larger than supported by driver
[    6.403125] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: TLV_FW_FSEQ_VERSION: FSEQ Version: 93.8.63.28
[    6.403475] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: loaded firmware version 59.601f3a66.0 ty-a0-gf-a0-59.ucode op_mode iwlmvm
[    6.426172] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Wi-Fi 6 AX210 160MHz, REV=0x420
[    6.574747] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: loaded PNVM version 0x324cd670
[    6.823134] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Timeout waiting for PNVM load!
[    6.823138] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Failed to start RT ucode: -110
[    6.823142] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: iwl_trans_send_cmd bad state = 1
[    7.027062] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: firmware didn't ACK the reset - continue anyway
[    7.039125] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Failed to run INIT ucode: -110
[   66.840923] Modules linked in: rfcomm cmac algif_hash algif_skcipher af_alg bnep nvidia_uvm(PO) nvidia_drm(PO) nvidia_modeset(PO) snd_sof_pci snd_sof_intel_hda_common snd_sof_intel_hda snd_sof_intel_byt intel_rapl_msr snd_sof_intel_ipc intel_rapl_common snd_sof snd_sof_xtensa_dsp snd_soc_hdac_hda x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp snd_hda_ext_core nvidia(PO) i915 snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_soc_acpi_intel_match snd_soc_acpi ledtrig_audio i2c_algo_bit snd_hda_intel snd_intel_dspcfg soundwire_intel soundwire_generic_allocation iwlmvm soundwire_cadence snd_hda_codec snd_hda_core soundwire_bus coretemp snd_usb_audio mac80211 snd_soc_core mei_hdcp snd_usbmidi_lib snd_compress ac97_bus snd_hwdep kvm_intel mc snd_pcm_dmaengine libarc4 snd_pcm kvm snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event snd_rawmidi nls_iso8859_1 crct10dif_pclmul btusb iwlwifi ghash_clmulni_intel btrtl aesni_intel snd_seq btbcm btintel snd_seq_device crypto_simd bluetooth snd_timer drm_kms_helper cryptd ecdh_generic glue_helper wmi_bmof
```

Comment: Have you rebooted router, and tried connecting to that same network with other devices?  If you are sure it is your OS software, you should be able to bring it up manually with `nmcli`, but I would troubleshoot thoroughly first. [Here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1356442/ubuntu-20-04-cannot-connect-to-wifi-wifi-settings-not-visible/1356547#1356547) is an older answer of mine w/ `nmcli` usage listed.

Comment: Please edit yor question to show the result of the terminal command: `sudo dmesg | grep iwl`

Comment: @chili555 I've  updated question with sudo dmesg | grep iwl command output

Comment: I don't think we need numerous threads covering the same bug and fix - see here: [Intel Wifi 6 AX210 - WiFi not working after Update](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1360175/intel-wifi-6-ax210-wifi-not-working-after-update)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This command provides greater details around the hardware capabilities of specific adapters.](https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/network-configuration#:%7E:text=sudo%20lshw%20%2Dclass%20network)

In the terminal:

```
sudo lshw -class network
```

[Kernel Bug 212371 - iwlwifi](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=212371)

[image]

[Intel AX210 Wi-Fi card does not work since updating to 1.196](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-firmware/+bug/1922406)

Renaming file iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0.pnvm to iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0.pnvm.old

In the terminal:

```
sudo mv /usr/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0.pnvm  /usr/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0.pnvm.old
```

Comment: Renaming worked. Thank you very much, you saved my days of time.