# Intel Wi-Fi 6 AX210 stops working Ubuntu 20.04.3

Tags: networking, 20.04, iwlwifi

I have a ThinkPad P14s running Ubuntu 20.04.3 and I used to have [this problem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1360175/intel-wifi-5-ax210-wifi-not-working-after-update) and [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1360291/26834) used to work.

A couple of days ago, my WiFi stopped working again - presumably after an upgrade. This time, the above solution no longer solves the problem and the kernel messages are different:

```
[   68.475159] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[   68.488513] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: api flags index 2 larger than supported by driver
[   68.488533] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: TLV_FW_FSEQ_VERSION: FSEQ Version: 0.0.2.25
[   68.489009] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: loaded firmware version 63.c04f3485.0 ty-a0-gf-a0-63.ucode op_mode iwlmvm
[   68.623466] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Wi-Fi 6 AX210 160MHz, REV=0x420
[   68.803885] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: Microcode SW error detected. Restarting 0x0.
[   68.803996] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: Start IWL Error Log Dump:
[   68.803999] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: Status: 0x00000040, count: 6
[   68.804001] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: Loaded firmware version: 63.c04f3485.0 ty-a0-gf-a0-63.ucode
[   68.804003] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00000071 | NMI_INTERRUPT_UMAC_FATAL    
[   68.804006] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x002002F0 | trm_hw_status0
[   68.804008] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00000000 | trm_hw_status1
[   68.804009] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x004DA004 | branchlink2
[   68.804011] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x004D07EA | interruptlink1
[   68.804012] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x004D07EA | interruptlink2
[   68.804014] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x004D8DEA | data1
[   68.804016] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00000010 | data2
[   68.804017] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00000000 | data3
[   68.804019] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00000000 | beacon time
[   68.804020] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00013757 | tsf low
[   68.804022] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00000000 | tsf hi
[   68.804023] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00000000 | time gp1
[   68.804025] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x0002859D | time gp2
[   68.804027] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00000001 | uCode revision type
[   68.804028] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x0000003F | uCode version major
[   68.804030] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0xC04F3485 | uCode version minor
[   68.804032] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00000420 | hw version
[   68.804033] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00489002 | board version
[   68.804035] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x8008FF00 | hcmd
[   68.804036] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00020000 | isr0
[   68.804038] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x60000000 | isr1
[   68.804040] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x58F00002 | isr2
[   68.804041] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00C0000C | isr3
[   68.804043] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00000000 | isr4
[   68.804045] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00000000 | last cmd Id
[   68.804046] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x004D8DEA | wait_event
[   68.804048] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00000000 | l2p_control
[   68.804050] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00000000 | l2p_duration
[   68.804051] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00000000 | l2p_mhvalid
[   68.804053] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00000000 | l2p_addr_match
[   68.804054] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00000009 | lmpm_pmg_sel
[   68.804056] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00000000 | timestamp
[   68.804058] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00000024 | flow_handler
[   68.804112] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: Start IWL Error Log Dump:
[   68.804113] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: Status: 0x00000040, count: 7
[   68.804115] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x2010070D | ADVANCED_SYSASSERT
[   68.804117] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00000000 | umac branchlink1
[   68.804118] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x8045CF40 | umac branchlink2
[   68.804120] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x0108E0B2 | umac interruptlink1
[   68.804122] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00000000 | umac interruptlink2
[   68.804124] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00000005 | umac data1
[   68.804125] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0xDEADBEEF | umac data2
[   68.804127] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0xDEADBEEF | umac data3
[   68.804128] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x0000003F | umac major
[   68.804130] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0xC04F3485 | umac minor
[   68.804132] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00028596 | frame pointer
[   68.804133] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0xC0885E90 | stack pointer
[   68.804135] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00010C00 | last host cmd
[   68.804137] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00000000 | isr status reg
[   68.804165] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: IML/ROM dump:
[   68.804166] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00000B03 | IML/ROM error/state
[   68.804185] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x000086A0 | IML/ROM data1
[   68.804197] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00000080 | IML/ROM WFPM_AUTH_KEY_0
[   68.804204] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: Fseq Registers:
[   68.804216] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x20000000 | FSEQ_ERROR_CODE
[   68.804228] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x80440002 | FSEQ_TOP_INIT_VERSION
[   68.804240] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00080009 | FSEQ_CNVIO_INIT_VERSION
[   68.804252] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x0000A652 | FSEQ_OTP_VERSION
[   68.804264] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00000002 | FSEQ_TOP_CONTENT_VERSION
[   68.804276] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x4552414E | FSEQ_ALIVE_TOKEN
[   68.804288] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00400410 | FSEQ_CNVI_ID
[   68.804300] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00400410 | FSEQ_CNVR_ID
[   68.804312] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00400410 | CNVI_AUX_MISC_CHIP
[   68.804326] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00400410 | CNVR_AUX_MISC_CHIP
[   68.804340] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00009061 | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_DIG_DCDC_VTRIM
[   68.804354] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00000061 | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_ACTIVE_VDIG_MIRROR
[   68.804370] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: WRT: Collecting data: ini trigger 13 fired (delay=0ms).
[   69.743608] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: Failed to run INIT ucode: -5
```

I have tried finding solutions for this symptom here and in other fora, but nothing seems like quite the same problem to me so far. For example, [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1387481/6e-ax210-pcie-wifi-card-not-working-on-ubuntu-20-04-5-11-kernel) concerns the same WiFi HW, but the error messages are different and the suggested solution of hiding the *.pnvm file does not solve my problem).
Do you have any good ideas for solving this one?

**Update**

Additional info:

```
$ ls -al /usr/lib/firmware/*.pnvm
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 41804 jan 10 11:19 /usr/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-so-a0-gf-a0.pnvm

$ ls -al /usr/lib/firmware/*.bak
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 27456 jan 10 11:19 /usr/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0.bak
```

As suggested in the comments, I have tried renaming "usr/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-so-a0-gf-a0.pnvm" to "usr/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-so-a0-gf-a0.pnvm.bak" to hide it, but this has not solved my problem after a reboot.

**Update 2**

By booting with a previously installed kernel, I can now see that WiFi works under kernel "5.11.0-46-generic", but does not under "5.13.0-25-generic" nor "5.13.0-27-generic".

Kernel 5.11.0-46-generic says (in `dmesg`):

```
iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: loaded firmware version 59.601f3a66.0 ty-a0-gf-a0-59.ucode op_mode iwlmvm
```

**and it works.**

Kernel 5.13.0-27-generic says:

```
iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: loaded firmware version 63.c04f3485.0 ty-a0-gf-a0-63.ucode op_mode iwlmvm
```

**and that does not work.**

My conclusion so far is that something broke between those two combinations of kernel version and WiFi firmware version. So far, it solves my problem to stay at kernel 5.11.0-46, but I will of course need a solution going forward so that I can use newer kernels.

I have reported this to Ubuntu as a [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-signed-hwe-5.13/+bug/1958639).

Comment: Show me `ls -al /usr/lib/firmware/*.pnvm` and `ls -al /usr/lib/firmware/*.bak`.

Comment: OK, updated above.

Comment: Rename the .pnvm file to .pnvm.bak. Reboot. Retest wifi. Report back.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [6E AX210 PCIE WiFi Card not working on ubuntu 20.04, 5.11 kernel](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1387481/6e-ax210-pcie-wifi-card-not-working-on-ubuntu-20-04-5-11-kernel)

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately renaming the *.pnvm file to hide it does not solve my problem this time.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Intel Wifi 6 AX210 - WiFi not working after Update](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1360175/intel-wifi-6-ax210-wifi-not-working-after-update)

Comment: @ArturMeinild unfortunately that's the question I mention in the beginning of my question, which used to work but no longer does.

Comment: @Someone I did not manually upgrade my kernel to 5.13. It came as an automatic update. I suppose I can somehow pin apt to stay at 5.11, but then wouldn't I have to manually keep revisiting the issue to figure out when it is safe to let it upgrade to a newer kernel?

Comment: @ThomasArildsen Well, maybe they fixed the .ucode that started all this... try renaming the two .bak files back to .pnvm, reboot and retest. Start comments to me with "@heynnema" or I'll miss them

Comment: Please see the comment below my answer here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1388922/ubuntu-20-04-no-wifi-adapter-found-due-to-microcode-sw-error-detected-iwlwifi/1388993#1388993

Comment: Great @chili555, his workaround works for me!