# WiFi6E card "AX210" is not working on ubuntu 20.04.04 / 22.04

Tags: iwlwifi, wpa-supplicant, wpa3

I am trying to connect WiFi-6E Access point with AX210 card installed on ubuntu20.04.04 with kernel 5.10.0.
i have removed/renamed the pvnm file as suggested [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1387481/6e-ax210-pcie-wifi-card-not-working-on-ubuntu-20-04-5-11-kernel) the wifi card is configured well as i dont see any error in

sudo dmesg | grep iwl.

i am using wpa_supplicant ( version 2.9) to connect to Wifi access point. My wpa_supplicant.conf looks like.

```
p2p_disabled=1
network={
        ssid="wifitest6E"
        #psk="aaaa1111"
        psk=edf145768310b75d365dfc1e3befb58c782e6d9ac63df83a709d200a6a238492
        key_mgmt=SAE
        sae_password="aaaa1111"
        ieee80211w=2
}
```

i am getting the following error in log when i run the command below.

```
sudo wpa_supplicant -d -c /etc/wpa_supplicant.conf -i wlp1s0


wlp1s0: 17: 1c:9e:cc:21:99:7a ssid='wifitest6E' wpa_ie_len=0 rsn_ie_len=20 caps=0x1111 level=-43 freq=7055
wlp1s0:    selected based on RSN IE
wlp1s0:    hardware does not support required rate 61.5 Mbps (freq=7055 mode==2 num_rates=8)
wlp1s0:    skip - rate sets do not match
```

iwlist freq gives the following optput

Cleared the older logs and adding the logs with just one wifi210 card.

```
Last login: Sat May 28 22:49:11 2022
ts@wifi6:~$ sudo dmesg | grep iwl
[sudo] password for umtts:
[   25.148201] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: api flags index 2 larger than supported by driver
[   25.148237] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: TLV_FW_FSEQ_VERSION: FSEQ Version: 0.63.2.2
[   25.149067] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: loaded firmware version 66.f1c864e0.0 ty-a0-gf-a0-66.ucode op_mode iwlmvm
[   25.857798] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Wi-Fi 6 AX210 160MHz, REV=0x420
[   26.195874] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: loaded PNVM version 0x5a8dfca
[   26.210726] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Detected RF GF, rfid=0x10d000
[   26.278930] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: base HW address: f4:7b:09:f8:ed:3c
[   26.491689] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0 wlp3s0: renamed from wlan0
ts@wifi6:~$

wlp3s0    32 channels in total; available frequencies :
          Channel 01 : 2.412 GHz
          Channel 02 : 2.417 GHz
          Channel 03 : 2.422 GHz
          Channel 04 : 2.427 GHz
          Channel 05 : 2.432 GHz
          Channel 06 : 2.437 GHz
          Channel 07 : 2.442 GHz
          Channel 08 : 2.447 GHz
          Channel 09 : 2.452 GHz
          Channel 10 : 2.457 GHz
          Channel 11 : 2.462 GHz
          Channel 12 : 2.467 GHz
          Channel 13 : 2.472 GHz
          Channel 14 : 2.484 GHz
          Channel 36 : 5.18 GHz
          Channel 40 : 5.2 GHz
          Channel 44 : 5.22 GHz
          Channel 48 : 5.24 GHz
          Channel 52 : 5.26 GHz
          Channel 56 : 5.28 GHz
          Channel 60 : 5.3 GHz
          Channel 64 : 5.32 GHz
          Channel 68 : 5.34 GHz
          Channel 72 : 5.36 GHz
          Channel 76 : 5.38 GHz
          Channel 80 : 5.4 GHz
          Channel 84 : 5.42 GHz
          Channel 88 : 5.44 GHz
          Channel 92 : 5.46 GHz
          Channel 96 : 5.48 GHz
          Channel 100 : 5.5 GHz
          Channel 104 : 5.52 GHz
ts@wifi6:~$
```

sudo wpa_supplicant -d -c /etc/wpa_supplicant.conf -i wlp3s0

```
wlp3s0:    selected based on RSN IE
wlp3s0:    SAE H2E disabled
wlp3s0:    skip - rate sets do not match
```

i added the below line in wpasupplicant.conf and the wifi interface could connect the access point :)

sae_pwe=1

Comment: Comments have  been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136679/discussion-on-question-by-pkm-wifi6e-card-ax210-is-not-working-on-ubuntu-20-04) for your convenience :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for posting this, that fixed my issue too.

The sae_pwe=1 configuration option is only supported from wpa_supplicant 2.10 (which currently is the latest release) onwards. Current version distributed with Debian is 2.9. So you might need to upgrade wpa_supplicant to 2.10 first to enable sae_pwe=1. Otherwise, wpa_supplicant will complain about unknown configuration option.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1250670)