# WiFi(Killer WiFi AX210) doesn't work on Ubuntu 20.04.2 from the get go

Tags: wireless, msi

I have a new MSI GS66 Stealth and the WiFi doesn't work on it from the get go while installing Ubuntu.(It did not recoganize the touchpad as well but I was able to make it work by following the [first answer on stackoverflow](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1235067/touchpad-stopped-working-20-04).)It says that no WifI adapter is found. I have dual booted the system with Windows 10 and the internet works fine on Windows.

Following is some of the information that could help you to understand the issue better.

1. Wireless Adapter: Intel® Wi-Fi 6E AX210 160MHz (Pre-installed when bought)
2. Laptop: MSI GS66 Stealth
3. OS: dual-booting with Windows 10 and Ubuntu20.04.02
4. Kernel version (#uname -r): 5.11.0-43-generic
5. Wireless performance on different OS: wifi works fine on Windows 10, but only on Ubuntu, from the get-go, it does not.
6. Other settings: disabled the "fast-boot" option on Windows, disabled the "secure boot" from Windows
7. Logs from useful commands

```
rfkill list
0: hci0: Bluetooth
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
```

```
lsmod | grep iwlwifi

returns nothing
```

```
sudo lshw -C network

*-network UNCLAIMED
description: Network controller
product: Intel Corporation
vendor: Intel Corporation
physical id: 0
bus info: pci@0000:30:00.0
version: 1a
width: 64 bits
clock: 33MHz
capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix cap_list
configuration: latency=0
resources: memory:84200000-84203fff
*-network
description: Ethernet interface
physical id: 2
bus info: usb@3:2
logical name: usb0
serial: 46:e1:9e:e4:65:18
capabilities: ethernet physical
configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rndis_host driverversion=5.11.0-43-generic firmware=RNDIS device ip=192.168.42.38 link=yes multicast=yes
```

```
dmesg | grep iwlwifi

returns nothing
```

I have followed the instructions given on https://community.intel.com/t5/Wireless/No-Wi-Fi-Adapter-Found-Intel-AX210-on-Ubuntu-20-04/m-p/12958, [No WiFi Adapter Found with fresh Ubuntu 20.04 install on MSI GE66 Laptop, and other strange behavior](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1324314/no-wifi-adapter-found-with-fresh-ubuntu-20-04-install-on-msi-ge66-laptop-and-ot), [Intel Wifi 5 AX210 - WiFi not working after Update](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1360175/intel-wifi-5-ax210-wifi-not-working-after-update) but with no effect.

Can someone give me any pointers on what to do? I'm seriously lost and I need the wifi inorder to do work on it. I have also posted the question [here](https://community.intel.com/t5/Wireless/WiFi-Killer-WiFi-AX210-doesn-t-work-on-Ubuntu-20-04-2-from-the/m-p/1346167#M39481)(contains some log files)

Thanks in advance!

---

I tried the following things for MSI GS66 Stealth:

1. Ubuntu 20.04 - WiFi and touch pad doesn't work. Touch pad can be made to work.
2. Ubuntu 20.04 + Kernel 5.13 - The kernel compilation wasn't successful.
3. Ubuntu 21.14 - Reaches end of life in January and WiFi and touch pad don't work
4. Ubuntu 21.10 - WiFi and touch pad work from the get go but I'm not able to install it as it doesn't recognize my SSD.

Now I'm using Ubuntu 20.04, the touch pad works by following the post I mentioned in the Question and I'm using an external wireless card (Panda Wireless PAU 06 Wireless 300 Mbps). It works for my system.

Answer (score 3):

AX210 is not supported by older kernels, it wasn't until about kernel 5.11 that support for AX210 began showing up.  It is supported in Ubuntu 21.10 out of the box as I have that same WIFI chipset working just fine (21.10 ships with kernel 5.13).

Run `uname -r` and that will give you your kernel version.  I am sure you will find it's quite old.

Your options:

1. Upgrade your kernel to the latest tested for 20.04 using `sudo apt update && sudo apt dist-upgrade && sudo apt autoremove`. Once done, reboot.  This may not get you to the latest kernel as it only installs the latest *tested* kernel for 20.04.  Run `uname -r` to see where you end up after the reboot.
2. Upgrade to or clean install Ubuntu 21.10
3. Manually upgrade your kernel to the latest available if you must stay on 20.04.  This is not recommended as it may cause stability issues with your OS.

Comment: +1 for upgrading to 21.10. Running a two-year-old OS on shiny new hardware only makes sense if all the hardware is recognized by the kernel.

Comment: Thanks @Debounce and user535733. I tried installing 21.10 but it was not compatible with my laptop. I also tried installing kernel 5.13 with Ubuntu 20.04 but it didn't lead to good results. If someone's laptop is compatible with 21.10 I would suggest using it as wifi and touchpad started working from the get go.