# Ubuntu 20.04 with Kernel 5.13.0-30-generic doesn't recognize RTX 3080 ti Laptop GPU, Blueetooth and WIFI 6

Tags: 20.04, nvidia, kernel, gpu

I have a new MSI RAIDER GE66 gaming laptop which has a RTX3080ti Laptop GPU. I want to use that laptop with Ubuntu 20.04. I tried to download nvidia driver but all the time I have problem with nvidia-smi or black screen issue. You can see some outputs below. Does anyone know the solution?

I have disabled Fast and secure boot

sudo lshw -C display output

```
  *-display UNCLAIMED       
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: NVIDIA Corporation
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: iomemory:600-5ff iomemory:640-63f memory:83000000-83ffffff memory:6000000000-63ffffffff memory:6400000000-6401ffffff ioport:5000(size=128) memory:84000000-8407ffff
  *-display UNCLAIMED
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Intel Corporation
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 0c
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: iomemory:640-63f iomemory:400-3ff memory:642c000000-642cffffff memory:4000000000-400fffffff ioport:6000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff memory:4010000000-4016ffffff memory:4020000000-40ffffffff
```

nvidia-smi

```
NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver. Make 
sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running.
```

ubuntu-drivers devices

```
== /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.0 ==
modalias : pci:v000010DEd00002420sv00001462sd00001320bc03sc00i00
vendor   : NVIDIA Corporation
driver   : nvidia-driver-510 - third-party non-free recommended
driver   : xserver-xorg-video-nouveau - distro free builtin
```

sudo lspci output

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Device 4641 (rev 02)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 460d (rev 02)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 46a6 (rev 0c)
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Device 461d (rev 02)
00:06.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 464d (rev 02)
00:07.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 466e (rev 02)
00:08.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Device 464f (rev 02)
00:0d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Device 461e (rev 02)
00:0d.2 USB controller: Intel Corporation Device 463e (rev 02)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Device 51ed (rev 01)
00:14.2 RAM memory: Intel Corporation Device 51ef (rev 01)
00:14.3 Network controller: Intel Corporation Device 51f0 (rev 01)
00:15.0 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Device 51e8 (rev 01)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Device 51e0 (rev 01)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 51b8 (rev 01)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 51bc (rev 01)
00:1c.7 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 51bf (rev 01)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Device 5182 (rev 01)
00:1f.3 Multimedia audio controller: Intel Corporation Device 51c8 (rev 01)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Device 51a3 (rev 01)
00:1f.5 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Device 51a4 (rev 01)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation Device 2420 (rev a1)
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation Device 2288 (rev a1)
02:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Micron Technology Inc Device 5407
2e:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device 5261 (rev 01)
2f:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device 3000 (rev 06)
```

dkms status

```
backport-iwlwifi, 8324: added
nvidia, 510.54, 5.13.0-30-generic, x86_64: installed
```

dpkg -l *nvidia*

```
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name                             Version                     Architecture Description
+++-================================-===========================-============-=========================================================
un  libgldispatch0-nvidia            <none>                      <none>       (no description available)
ii  libnvidia-cfg1-510:amd64         510.54-0ubuntu0.20.04.1     amd64        NVIDIA binary OpenGL/GLX configuration library
un  libnvidia-cfg1-any               <none>                      <none>       (no description available)
un  libnvidia-common                 <none>                      <none>       (no description available)
ii  libnvidia-common-510             510.54-0ubuntu0.20.04.1     all          Shared files used by the NVIDIA libraries
un  libnvidia-compute                <none>                      <none>       (no description available)
rc  libnvidia-compute-470:amd64      470.103.01-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 amd64        NVIDIA libcompute package
ii  libnvidia-compute-510:amd64      510.54-0ubuntu0.20.04.1     amd64        NVIDIA libcompute package
ii  libnvidia-compute-510:i386       510.54-0ubuntu0.20.04.1     i386         NVIDIA libcompute package
un  libnvidia-decode                 <none>                      <none>       (no description available)
ii  libnvidia-decode-510:amd64       510.54-0ubuntu0.20.04.1     amd64        NVIDIA Video Decoding runtime libraries
ii  libnvidia-decode-510:i386        510.54-0ubuntu0.20.04.1     i386         NVIDIA Video Decoding runtime libraries
un  libnvidia-encode                 <none>                      <none>       (no description available)
ii  libnvidia-encode-510:amd64       510.54-0ubuntu0.20.04.1     amd64        NVENC Video Encoding runtime library
ii  libnvidia-encode-510:i386        510.54-0ubuntu0.20.04.1     i386         NVENC Video Encoding runtime library
un  libnvidia-extra                  <none>                      <none>       (no description available)
ii  libnvidia-extra-510:amd64        510.54-0ubuntu0.20.04.1     amd64        Extra libraries for the NVIDIA driver
un  libnvidia-fbc1                   <none>                      <none>       (no description available)
ii  libnvidia-fbc1-510:amd64         510.54-0ubuntu0.20.04.1     amd64        NVIDIA OpenGL-based Framebuffer Capture runtime library
ii  libnvidia-fbc1-510:i386          510.54-0ubuntu0.20.04.1     i386         NVIDIA OpenGL-based Framebuffer Capture runtime library
un  libnvidia-gl                     <none>                      <none>       (no description available)
ii  libnvidia-gl-510:amd64           510.54-0ubuntu0.20.04.1     amd64        NVIDIA OpenGL/GLX/EGL/GLES GLVND libraries and Vulkan ICD
ii  libnvidia-gl-510:i386            510.54-0ubuntu0.20.04.1     i386         NVIDIA OpenGL/GLX/EGL/GLES GLVND libraries and Vulkan ICD
un  libnvidia-ml1                    <none>                      <none>       (no description available)
un  nvidia-384                       <none>                      <none>       (no description available)
un  nvidia-390                       <none>                      <none>       (no description available)
un  nvidia-common                    <none>                      <none>       (no description available)
un  nvidia-compute-utils             <none>                      <none>       (no description available)
ii  nvidia-compute-utils-510         510.54-0ubuntu0.20.04.1     amd64        NVIDIA compute utilities
ii  nvidia-dkms-510                  510.54-0ubuntu0.20.04.1     amd64        NVIDIA DKMS package
un  nvidia-dkms-kernel               <none>                      <none>       (no description available)
ii  nvidia-driver-510                510.54-0ubuntu0.20.04.1     amd64        NVIDIA driver metapackage
un  nvidia-driver-binary             <none>                      <none>       (no description available)
un  nvidia-kernel-common             <none>                      <none>       (no description available)
ii  nvidia-kernel-common-510         510.54-0ubuntu0.20.04.1     amd64        Shared files used with the kernel module
un  nvidia-kernel-source             <none>                      <none>       (no description available)
ii  nvidia-kernel-source-510         510.54-0ubuntu0.20.04.1     amd64        NVIDIA kernel source package
un  nvidia-legacy-304xx-vdpau-driver <none>                      <none>       (no description available)
un  nvidia-legacy-340xx-vdpau-driver <none>                      <none>       (no description available)
un  nvidia-libopencl1-dev            <none>                      <none>       (no description available)
un  nvidia-opencl-icd                <none>                      <none>       (no description available)
un  nvidia-persistenced              <none>                      <none>       (no description available)
ii  nvidia-prime                     0.8.16~0.20.04.1            all          Tools to enable NVIDIA's Prime
ii  nvidia-settings                  470.57.01-0ubuntu0.20.04.3  amd64        Tool for configuring the NVIDIA graphics driver
un  nvidia-settings-binary           <none>                      <none>       (no description available)
un  nvidia-smi                       <none>                      <none>       (no description available)
un  nvidia-utils                     <none>                      <none>       (no description available)
ii  nvidia-utils-510                 510.54-0ubuntu0.20.04.1     amd64        NVIDIA driver support binaries
un  nvidia-vdpau-driver              <none>                      <none>       (no description available)
ii  xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-510    510.54-0ubuntu0.20.04.1     amd64        NVIDIA binary Xorg driver
```

Ubuntu 21.10 sudo lshw -C display output

```
*-display UNCLAIMED
    description: VGA compatible controller
    product: NVIDIA Corporation
    vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
    physical id: ©
    bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
    version: al
    width: 64 bits
    clock: 33MHZ
    capabilities: pm si pciexpress vga_controller cap_list
    configuration: latency=0
    resources: tonemory: 600-5ff tonemory:640-63f memory:83000000-83ffffff menory:6000000000-63ffffffff nenory:6400000000-6401ffffff toport:5000(size=128) memory:84000000-8407ffff
*-display UNCLAIMED
    description: VGA compatible controller
    product: Intel Corporation
    vendor: Intel Corporation
    physical id: 2
    bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
    version: Oc
    width: 64 bits
    clock: 33MHz
    capabilities: pctexpress mst pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list
    configuration: latency=0
    resources: tomemory:640-63f tomemory:400-3ff memory: 642c000000-642cffffff memory: 4000000000-400fffffff toport:6000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff memory: 4010000000-4016ffffff memory: 4020000000-40ffffffff
```

Ubuntu 21.10 sudo dmidecode -s bios-version output

```
E1544IMS.202
```

Ubuntu 21.10 sudo lshw -C video

```
*-display UNCLAIMED
    description: VGA compatible controller
    product: NVIDIA Corporation
    vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
    physical id: o
    bus info: pet@0000: 01:00.0
    version: al
    width: 64 bits
    clock: 33MHz
    capabilities: pm mst pciexpress vga_controller cap_list
    configuration: latency=0
    resources: tomemory:600-5ff tomemory:640-63f memory:
83000000-83ffffff memory:6000000000-63ffffffff menory:6400000000-6401ffffff toport:5000(size=128) memory:84000000-8407ffff
*-display UNCLAIMED
    description: VGA compatible controller
    product: Intel Corporation
    vendor: Intel Corporation
    physical id: 2
    bus info: pci@000O:00:02.0
    version: Oc
    width: 64 bits
    clock: 33MHZ
    capabilities: pciexpress mst pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list
    configuration: latency=0
    resources: iomemory:640-638 iomemory:400-3ff memory:642c000000-642cffffff menary:4000000000-400fffffff iop
ort: 6000(size=64) memory:c®000-dffff memory: 4010000000-4016ffffff memory: 4020000000-40ffffffff
```

Ubuntu 21.10 sudo lshw -C network

```
*-network UNCLAIMED
    description: Network controller
    product: Intel Corporation
    vendor: Intel Corporation
    physical id: 14.3
    bus info: pci@0000:00:14.3
    version: 01
    width: 64 bits
    clock: 33MHZ
    capabilities: pm msi pciexpress nsix cap list
    configuration: latency=0
    resources: tonemory:640-63f memory:642d184000-642d187fff
*-network
    description: Ethernet interface
    product: Killer E3000 2.5GbE Controller
    vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
    physical id: o
    bus info: pciqoo0o: 2f:00.0
    logical name: enp47s
    version: 06
    serial: d8:bb:c1:b1:1d:c1
    capacity: 1Gbit/s
    width: 64 bits
    clock: 33MHz
    capabilities: pm mst petexpress mstx vpd bus master cap_list ethernet phystcal tp nit 10bt 10bt-f
d 100bt 100bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd1000bt-fd autonegotiation
    configuration: autonegottation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=S.13.0-19-genertc ftrnwareert8125b-2
_0.0.2 07/13/20 latency=© linkano multicastayes portatwisted pair
    resources: 1rq:19 toport:3000(stze=256) memory:84c00000-84c0ffff memory: 84c10000-84c13fff
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134384/discussion-on-question-by-serdar-akyol-ubuntu-20-04-with-kernel-5-13-0-30-generi).

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I could not fix the problem with Ubuntu 20.04.I installed Ubuntu 21.10, then installed nvidia-drivers via `Additional Driver` and it's working now. Bluetooth was working with Ubuntu 21.10

nvidia-smi

```
Fri Feb 25 17:21:19 2022       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 510.47.03    Driver Version: 510.47.03    CUDA Version: 11.6     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  NVIDIA GeForce ...  Off  | 00000000:01:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| N/A   35C    P3    N/A /  N/A |      5MiB / 16384MiB |      0%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                               
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0   N/A  N/A      1656      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                  4MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I solved WiFi problem from that [link](https://askubuntu.com/a/1324339/1573725).
The link summery as below

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt-get install -y git
sudo apt-get install -y build-essential

git clone git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git
cd linux-firmware
sudo cp iwlwifi-* /lib/firmware/
cd ..

git clone https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/iwlwifi/backport-iwlwifi.git
cd backport-iwlwifi
make defconfig-iwlwifi-public
make -j4
sudo make install
 
sudo update-initramfs -u
sudo reboot
```

Comment: Check the vendor for any firmware updates, and try the alpha version of 22.04, which has a later kernel, which also might help.