# "Wifi Adapter not Found" on Asus running Ubuntu 22.04, how do I diagnose the problem?

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, 22.04, realtek-wireless

```
Machine       : ASUS X550VX
System        : Ubuntu 22.04
Kernel        : 5.15.0-40-generic
Wireless Card : Realtek RTL8723BE
```

Suddenly my wifi is gone and there is no option to turn it on, it says "No wifi adapter found". It was just fine before, I didn't mess with any network settings and it's been 2 days now that my wifi isn't working. There has been no luck with update from `apt update` and `apt dist-upgrade`.

[image]

Information regarding my system :

**ifconfig -a**  (wifi is not even listed)

```
ifconfig -a                                                                                         
enp4s0f1: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 88:d7:f6:2f:85:a6  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 35160  bytes 2601514 (2.6 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 35160  bytes 2601514 (2.6 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

usb0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.45.57  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.45.255
        inet6 fe80::2455:ca2b:5322:97a0  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether ce:ce:11:66:e8:3e  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 72442  bytes 97471754 (97.4 MB)
        RX errors 1  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 1
        TX packets 31739  bytes 3779696 (3.7 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

**sudo lshw -c network**

```
sudo lshw -c network                                                                                  
      *-network UNCLAIMED       
           description: Network controller
           product: RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
           vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
           physical id: 0
           bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
           version: 00
           width: 64 bits
           clock: 33MHz
           capabilities: pm msi pciexpress cap_list
           configuration: latency=0
           resources: ioport:d000(size=256) memory:ef200000-ef203fff
      *-network
           description: Ethernet interface
           product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
           vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
           physical id: 0.1
           bus info: pci@0000:04:00.1
           logical name: enp4s0f1
           version: 12
           serial: 88:d7:f6:2f:85:a6
           capacity: 1Gbit/s
           width: 64 bits
           clock: 33MHz
           capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
           configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=5.15.0-40-generic firmware=rtl8411-2_0.0.1 07/08/13 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
           resources: irq:19 ioport:c000(size=256) memory:ef114000-ef114fff memory:ef110000-ef113fff
      *-network
           description: Ethernet interface
           physical id: b
           bus info: usb@1:5
           logical name: usb0
           serial: ce:ce:11:66:e8:3e
           capabilities: ethernet physical
           configuration: autonegotiation=off broadcast=yes driver=rndis_host driverversion=5.15.0-40-generic duplex=half firmware=RNDIS device ip=192.168.45.57 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair
```

**rfkill list all**

```
rfkill list all                                                                                  
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

**lspci -nnk | grep Net**

```
lspci -nnk | grep Net                                                                             
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:b723]
    Subsystem: Lite-On Communications Inc RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [11ad:8723]
```

What I have tried (with many reboots) :

1. `rfkill unblock all`
2. `sudo apt reinstall network-manager && sudo service network-manager restart`
3. `sudo snap install network-manager` (installing network manager via `snap`)
4. Installing `iwlwifi` following this thread : [No WiFi Adapter Found with fresh Ubuntu 20.04 install on MSI GE66 Laptop, and other strange behavior](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1324314/no-wifi-adapter-found-with-fresh-ubuntu-20-04-install-on-msi-ge66-laptop-and-ot)
5. Installing driver for RTL8723BE from `git clone https://github.com/lwfinger/rtw88.git`

All with no luck then I found some interesting information :

```
    sudo dmesg | grep rtl                                                                           
    [    5.510743] rtlwifi: disagrees about version of symbol ieee80211_connection_loss
    [    5.510746] rtlwifi: Unknown symbol ieee80211_connection_loss (err -22)
    [    5.510926] rtlwifi: disagrees about version of symbol ieee80211_start_tx_ba_session
    [    5.510928] rtlwifi: Unknown symbol ieee80211_start_tx_ba_session (err -22)
    [    5.510938] rtlwifi: disagrees about version of symbol ieee80211_rate_control_unregister
    [    5.510939] rtlwifi: Unknown symbol ieee80211_rate_control_unregister (err -22)
    [    5.510949] rtlwifi: disagrees about version of symbol ieee80211_get_hdrlen_from_skb
    [    5.510950] rtlwifi: Unknown symbol ieee80211_get_hdrlen_from_skb (err -22)
    [    5.510964] rtlwifi: disagrees about version of symbol ieee80211_find_sta
    [    5.510965] rtlwifi: Unknown symbol ieee80211_find_sta (err -22)
    [    5.510972] rtlwifi: disagrees about version of symbol ieee80211_tx_status_irqsafe
    [    5.510973] rtlwifi: Unknown symbol ieee80211_tx_status_irqsafe (err -22)
    [    5.510985] rtlwifi: disagrees about version of symbol cfg80211_put_bss
    [    5.510987] rtlwifi: Unknown symbol cfg80211_put_bss (err -22)
    [    5.510995] rtlwifi: disagrees about version of symbol ieee80211_stop_tx_ba_cb_irqsafe
    [    5.510997] rtlwifi: Unknown symbol ieee80211_stop_tx_ba_cb_irqsafe (err -22)
    [    5.511003] rtlwifi: disagrees about version of symbol wiphy_to_ieee80211_hw
    [    5.511004] rtlwifi: Unknown symbol wiphy_to_ieee80211_hw (err -22)
    [    5.511015] rtlwifi: disagrees about version of symbol wiphy_apply_custom_regulatory
    [    5.511016] rtlwifi: Unknown symbol wiphy_apply_custom_regulatory (err -22)
    [    5.511022] rtlwifi: disagrees about version of symbol ieee80211_rate_control_register
    [    5.511023] rtlwifi: Unknown symbol ieee80211_rate_control_register (err -22)
    [    5.511033] rtlwifi: disagrees about version of symbol cfg80211_get_bss
    [    5.511034] rtlwifi: Unknown symbol cfg80211_get_bss (err -22)
    [    5.511051] rtlwifi: disagrees about version of symbol wiphy_rfkill_set_hw_state_reason
    [    5.511053] rtlwifi: Unknown symbol wiphy_rfkill_set_hw_state_reason (err -22)
    [    5.511058] rtlwifi: disagrees about version of symbol wiphy_rfkill_start_polling
    [    5.511060] rtlwifi: Unknown symbol wiphy_rfkill_start_polling (err -22)
    [    5.511067] rtlwifi: disagrees about version of symbol freq_reg_info
    [    5.511068] rtlwifi: Unknown symbol freq_reg_info (err -22)
    [    5.511080] rtlwifi: disagrees about version of symbol ieee80211_resume_disconnect
    [    5.511081] rtlwifi: Unknown symbol ieee80211_resume_disconnect (err -22)
    [    5.511088] rtlwifi: disagrees about version of symbol ieee80211_beacon_get_tim
    [    5.511089] rtlwifi: Unknown symbol ieee80211_beacon_get_tim (err -22)
    [    5.511099] rtlwifi: disagrees about version of symbol cfg80211_unlink_bss
    [    5.511100] rtlwifi: Unknown symbol cfg80211_unlink_bss (err -22)
    [    5.511107] rtlwifi: disagrees about version of symbol ieee80211_rx_irqsafe
    [    5.511108] rtlwifi: Unknown symbol ieee80211_rx_irqsafe (err -22)
    [    5.939896] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: loading rtl_bt/rtl8723b_fw.bin
    [    5.941270] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: loading rtl_bt/rtl8723b_config.bin
    [    5.941298] bluetooth hci0: Direct firmware load for rtl_bt/rtl8723b_config.bin failed with error -2
```

I don't know what else to go or to try from here, any suggestions ?

**[UPDATE 02/06/2022]**

Following suggestion from comments, I removed `iwlwifi` dan include my [wireless info (gist)](https://gist.github.com/nowhere-girl/aec3b850362ed32f46bcf8ed15c215fc) following [My wireless/WiFi connection does not work. What information is needed to diagnose the issue?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos)

Comment: There are several methods listed in your link that can be used to install iwlwifi which is the wrong driver for your device and no doubt interfers with rtw88. Which exact method did you use?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My wireless/WiFi connection does not work. What information is needed to diagnose the issue?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos)

Comment: @waltinator the link suggested to update out post to attach the output of our wireless information taken from a script, which I already did just now, thank you. The post didn't exactly explain how to diagnose the output, therefore I am still looking for more advice.

Comment: @chili555 I built `iwlwifi` following the working solution from OP, however following your comment, I have manually removed `iwlwifi-*` from my `/lib/firmware` and I have uninstalled `backport-iwlwifi` as well.

Comment: You need to uninstall the rtw88 and whatever kernel backports you installed

Comment: The accepted answer says add a PPA and then install backport-iwlwifi-dkms ..OR.. build iwlwifi/backport-iwlwifi.git. We need to remove whichever you installed and the method to remove it depends on the method you used to install it.  Which was it?

Answer (score 1):

To solve the problem, I changed the kernel from 5.17 to 5.13. I then installed network drivers `iw`, `iwd`, `linssid`, `urfkill` and rebooted.

Comment: The default kernel for 22.04 is 5.15 is there a reason you are not using  it?

Comment: I was using the 5.15 but there was the same problem. I switched to 5.17 but the problem persisted.

Comment: how to switch kernel?

Comment: Go to advanced Ubuntu options into he launch and choose different kernel. This worked for me but can someone explain why?