# Bluetooth rapidly toggling on and off on MSI GE66 laptop running Ubuntu 20.10, using 100% of CPU

Tags: drivers, usb, bluetooth, 20.10

I just did a fresh install of Ubuntu 20.10 to my MSI GE66 laptop.
For some reason, the Bluetooth is rapidly toggling and on off.
Here is a video which demonstrates what is happeneing:
https://youtu.be/Y7kT3Nkxkag

Also when I run `htop` it shows that `systemd-udevd` is using 100% of my CPU (one of 16 threads on my machine).
Running `udevadm monitor` keeps printing the following:

```
KERNEL[14196.456057] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-14 (usb)
KERNEL[14196.457305] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-14/1-14:1.0 (usb)
KERNEL[14196.457336] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-14/1-14:1.0/bluetooth/hci0 (bluetooth)
KERNEL[14196.457376] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-14/1-14:1.0/bluetooth/hci0/rfkill24105 (rfkill)
KERNEL[14196.457501] bind     /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-14/1-14:1.0 (usb)
KERNEL[14196.457517] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-14/1-14:1.1 (usb)
KERNEL[14196.457541] bind     /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-14/1-14:1.1 (usb)
KERNEL[14196.457568] bind     /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-14 (usb)
UDEV  [14196.458030] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-14/1-14:1.0 (usb)
UDEV  [14196.458060] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-14/1-14:1.1 (usb)
UDEV  [14196.514604] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-14/1-14:1.0/bluetooth/hci0 (bluetooth)
KERNEL[14196.614800] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-14/1-14:1.0/bluetooth/hci0/rfkill24105 (rfkill)
KERNEL[14196.614815] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-14/1-14:1.0/bluetooth/hci0 (bluetooth)
KERNEL[14196.614824] unbind   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-14/1-14:1.1 (usb)
KERNEL[14196.614846] unbind   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-14/1-14:1.0 (usb)
KERNEL[14196.614857] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-14/1-14:1.0 (usb)
KERNEL[14196.614867] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-14/1-14:1.1 (usb)
KERNEL[14196.625238] unbind   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-14 (usb)
KERNEL[14196.625276] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-14 (usb)
UDEV  [14196.670293] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-14/1-14:1.0/bluetooth/hci0/rfkill4297 (rfkill)
KERNEL[14197.044037] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-14 (usb)
KERNEL[14197.045068] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-14/1-14:1.0 (usb)
KERNEL[14197.045100] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-14/1-14:1.0/bluetooth/hci0 (bluetooth)
KERNEL[14197.045128] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-14/1-14:1.0/bluetooth/hci0/rfkill24106 (rfkill)
KERNEL[14197.045203] bind     /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-14/1-14:1.0 (usb)
KERNEL[14197.045243] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-14/1-14:1.1 (usb)
KERNEL[14197.045273] bind     /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-14/1-14:1.1 (usb)
KERNEL[14197.045327] bind     /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-14 (usb)
UDEV  [14197.045651] bind     /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-14/1-14:1.1 (usb)
UDEV  [14197.045683] bind     /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-14/1-14:1.0 (usb)
KERNEL[14197.202815] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-14/1-14:1.0/bluetooth/hci0/rfkill24106 (rfkill)
KERNEL[14197.202852] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-14/1-14:1.0/bluetooth/hci0 (bluetooth)
KERNEL[14197.202862] unbind   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-14/1-14:1.1 (usb)
KERNEL[14197.202870] unbind   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-14/1-14:1.0 (usb)
KERNEL[14197.202895] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-14/1-14:1.0 (usb)
KERNEL[14197.202904] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-14/1-14:1.1 (usb)
KERNEL[14197.213432] unbind   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-14 (usb)
KERNEL[14197.213468] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-14 (usb)
KERNEL[14197.632034] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-14 (usb)
KERNEL[14197.633245] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-14/1-14:1.0 (usb)
KERNEL[14197.633276] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-14/1-14:1.0/bluetooth/hci0 (bluetooth)
KERNEL[14197.633284] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-14/1-14:1.0/bluetooth/hci0/rfkill24107 (rfkill)
KERNEL[14197.633380] bind     /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-14/1-14:1.0 (usb)
KERNEL[14197.633536] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-14/1-14:1.1 (usb)
KERNEL[14197.633572] bind     /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-14/1-14:1.1 (usb)
KERNEL[14197.633583] bind     /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-14 (usb)
UDEV  [14197.633872] bind     /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-14 (usb)
UDEV  [14197.650160] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-14/1-14:1.0/bluetooth/hci0/rfkill4297 (rfkill)
UDEV  [14197.650484] unbind   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-14/1-14:1.1 (usb)
KERNEL[14197.790798] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-14/1-14:1.0/bluetooth/hci0/rfkill24107 (rfkill)
KERNEL[14197.790837] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-14/1-14:1.0/bluetooth/hci0 (bluetooth)
KERNEL[14197.790862] unbind   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-14/1-14:1.1 (usb)
KERNEL[14197.790890] unbind   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-14/1-14:1.0 (usb)
KERNEL[14197.790915] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-14/1-14:1.0 (usb)
KERNEL[14197.790924] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-14/1-14:1.1 (usb)
KERNEL[14197.801383] unbind   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-14 (usb)
KERNEL[14197.801418] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-14 (usb)
UDEV  [14197.804361] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-14/1-14:1.0/bluetooth/hci0 (bluetooth)
UDEV  [14197.804580] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-14/1-14:1.1 (usb)
UDEV  [14197.957591] unbind   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-14/1-14:1.0 (usb)
UDEV  [14198.111830] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-14/1-14:1.0 (usb)
KERNEL[14198.220004] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-14 (usb)
KERNEL[14198.221202] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-14/1-14:1.0 (usb)
KERNEL[14198.221232] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-14/1-14:1.0/bluetooth/hci0 (bluetooth)
KERNEL[14198.221242] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-14/1-14:1.0/bluetooth/hci0/rfkill24108 (rfkill)
KERNEL[14198.221291] bind     /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-14/1-14:1.0 (usb)
KERNEL[14198.221391] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-14/1-14:1.1 (usb)
KERNEL[14198.221427] bind     /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-14/1-14:1.1 (usb)
KERNEL[14198.221461] bind     /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-14 (usb)
```

What exactly is going on? How can I solve this?

**Edit**

Here's some more info about my system.

Output of `sudo lshw | grep product`

```
    product: GE66 Raider 10UH (1542.1)
       product: MS-1542
             product: HMAA2GS6AJR8N-XN
             product: HMAA2GS6AJR8N-XN
          product: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-10870H CPU @ 2.20GHz
          product: 10th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers
             product: Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor PCIe Controller (x16)
                product: NVIDIA Corporation
                product: NVIDIA Corporation
             product: UHD Graphics
             product: Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Thermal Subsystem
             product: Comet Lake PCH Thermal Controller
             product: Comet Lake USB 3.1 xHCI Host Controller
                product: xHCI Host Controller
                   product: SteelSeries KLC
                   product: SteelSeries ALC
                   product: Integrated Camera
                product: xHCI Host Controller
             product: Comet Lake PCH Shared SRAM
             product: Comet Lake PCH Serial IO I2C Controller #0
             product: Comet Lake PCH Serial IO I2C Controller #2
             product: Comet Lake HECI Controller
             product: Comet Lake PCI Express Root Port #17
                product: ASMedia Technology Inc.
                   product: xHCI Host Controller
                   product: xHCI Host Controller
             product: Comet Lake PCI Express Root Port #9
                product: Sandisk Corp
                   product: WDC PC SN730 SDBPNTY-1T00-1032
             product: Intel Corporation
                product: Intel Corporation
             product: Intel Corporation
                product: Intel Corporation
             product: Intel Corporation
                product: RTS525A PCI Express Card Reader
             product: Comet Lake LPC Controller
             product: Comet Lake PCH cAVS
             product: Comet Lake PCH SMBus Controller
             product: Comet Lake PCH SPI Controller
          product: PnP device PNP0c02
          product: PnP device MSI0007
          product: PnP device PNP0f13
          product: PnP device PNP0c02
          product: PnP device PNP0b00
          product: PnP device INT3f0d
          product: PnP device PNP0c02
          product: PnP device PNP0c02
          product: PnP device PNP0c02
          product: PnP device PNP0c02
       product: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
```

Output of `spci -knn | grep Net -A3; lsusb`

```
04:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:2725] (rev 1a)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:0024]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 1038:1122 SteelSeries ApS SteelSeries KLC
Bus 001 Device 067: ID 8087:0032 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 5986:1160 Acer, Inc Integrated Camera
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 1038:1132 SteelSeries ApS SteelSeries ALC
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

**Edit 2**

Even if I can't get the bluetooth working that's fine. I'm ok just disabling it entirely, ultimately I just don't want it consuming CPU like it is right now.

**Edit 3**

Just did a fresh install of Ubuntu 20.04 instead, I have the same issue.

Comment: You can try a fresh install of Ubuntu 20.04 instead. If it works just stay on that version for a long time (five year life span). Ubuntu 20.10 only has a life span of 9 months from date of release.

Comment: I also tried with 20.04 and it experienced the same problem.

Comment: But yes I think I'll be downgrading to 20.04 b/c of the longer support.

Comment: Do you have the `Killer ax Wi-Fi + Bluetooth v5.1` or the `802.11 ax Wi-Fi 6 + Bluetooth v5.1`? (If you don't know, it may say when you run `lspci`). When you comment put @WinEunuuchs2Unix in the message or I will never see it.

Comment: Please test again using a pre-release (21.04 as of today) LiveUSB's "Try Ubuntu" environment. If the bug occurs in the pre-release version of Ubuntu, and if nobody has filed a bug report yet, then file the bug report. If there is an existing bug report already, subscribe to it and help test the fix when it appears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trying many things, I was able to fully disable my Bluetooth by doing the following:

`sudo vim /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf`

Then add the following line:
`blacklist btusb`

Then finally reboot.

The Bluetooth no longer toggles on and off, and no longer consumes CPU - though this is not a great solution b/c it ultimately involves disabling the Bluetooth.

Comment: *Any* workaround to a bug is considered "not a great solution". The real, ultimate solution is to get the bug fixed. One assumes you filed a proper bug report. None of the developers intended Bluetooth to not work.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue on Ubuntu 20.04.02 with the 5.10.24 kernel.

Inserting the following line in `/etc/udev/rules.d/81-bluetooth-hci.rules` solved the problem for me:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="8087", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0032", ATTR{authorized}="0"
```

Basically, with the above setting you are disabling the Intel Bluetooth adapter.

Comment: I don't see to have a `81-bluetooth-hci.rules` file in `/etc/udev/rules.d/`, should I create one? I only have rules for snap packages.