# Changing the Grub menu does not change booting

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi

I have been trying to change the Grub to set Linux-Ubuntu as default option with no success since now I have to enter first to boot menu otherwise Windows starts. I have changed the `/etc/default/grubg` file as well as used the Grub Customizer App but apparently my laptop doesn't seem to accept the changes, it keeps loading Windows as default boot option.

Specifically I have been changing the lines within the `/etc/default/grub` file.
The current status of the file is the following:

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=saved
GRUB_SAVEDEFAULT="true"
#GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT="0"
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET="true"
GRUB_TIMEOUT="10"
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR="`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash intel_idle.max_cstate=1"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

# Uncomment to enable BadRAM filtering, modify to suit your needs
# This works with Linux (no patch required) and with any kernel that obtains
# the memory map information from GRUB (GNU Mach, kernel of FreeBSD ...)
#GRUB_BADRAM="0x01234567,0xfefefefe,0x89abcdef,0xefefefef"

# Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)
#GRUB_TERMINAL="console"

# The resolution used on graphical terminal
# note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
# you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
#GRUB_GFXMODE="640x480"

# Uncomment if you don't want GRUB to pass "root=UUID=xxx" parameter to Linux
#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID="true"
```

I have tried changing the default with several numbers from 0 to 2  and to switch on and off the option `GRUB_SAVEDEFAULT="true"` but the Laptop keeps behaving the same way.

---

I solved the issue thanks to oldfred's suggestion, specifically this link helped http://askubuntu.com/questions/485261/change-boot-order-using-efibootmgr

From my understanding Windows was referring to its configuration file named `shimx64.efi` and not to the `grub2` file. I therefore ran `boot repair` to fix any issue related to booting then I went on my windows and performed in Windows Administrator Command Prompt the following line:

```
bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi
```

Finally, it fixed the problem. Thanks to all

Comment: Have you run `sudo update-grub` after making your changes to the config file?  If you don't, your changes will have no effect.

Comment: Yes, with no success

Comment: I suggest editing your question and including the contents of your grub file, at least down to the BadRAM comment line, assuming you have made no changes below that.

Comment: Is this an UEFI system? Then UEFI choice must have Ubuntu entry as first.  http://askubuntu.com/questions/485261/change-boot-order-using-efibootmgr see also `man efibootmgr` And if an Acer you have to set "trust" on the ubuntu/grub entry from UEFI. https://askubuntu.com/questions/862946/unable-to-install-ubuntu-on-acer-aspire-es1-533

Answer (score 0):

With these two parameters in your /etc/default/grub:

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=saved
GRUB_SAVEDEFAULT=true # note the difference
```

it'll remember the LAST chosen OS. So select Ubuntu, and it'll default to Ubuntu on the next boot.

You must do a `sudo update-grub` after making changes to /etc/default/grub for this to work.

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work. So, I am currently on Linux, now if I reboot the system supposedly it should start Linux, however it keeps starting Windows. I mean, maybe I got this problem wrong, I am trying to set the booting configuration to have Linux start automatically, even though all these changes, the booting configuration starts with Windows no matter what settings I configure.

Comment: @Alessio_110 show me your full /etc/default/grub... replace the one in your question with a new copy/paste, and ping me at `@heynnema` or I may miss the update.