# Installation of Ubuntu 18.04 on an Acer with UEFI - grub installation doesn't work

Tags: boot, grub2, uefi, acer

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 18.04 on an Acer Aspire ES15 with UEFI. Originally,  it was delivered with Windows 10, but now I don't want to use them at all. The intention is to have only Linux here without some dual boot. The problem is when the installation comes to the `grub2` package.

I've found similar questions all around the different forums and also several methods to try. Unfortunately nothing helped me till now. I tried also different linux distros, but none of them worked. Finally I've found [this similar thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/862946/unable-to-install-ubuntu-on-acer-aspire-es1-533), so I was able to install the system without `grub` and then, when trying to install grub manually, it stopped me at

```
sudo grub-install --no-nvram --root-directory=/mnt
```

It says that the EFI directory can't be found.
I also tried to use boot-repair (recommended repair), but without success (now tried to install Linux Mint - same behavior like Ubuntu)

Here is the link for the boot repair summary: [boot repair summary](http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/KbrCTvN9tT/)

Can somebody tell me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your boot repair log says Linux Mint 19 is installed not Ubuntu 18.04?

Comment: Yes, I tried Ubuntu at first and the totally same behavior was there. Same approach, same error message. So I suppose the problem is somehow common for both.

Comment: Try a new Linux Mint 19 ISO download or install without internet

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem on this dell inspiron 11 3162 that I am using. I was successful in the end after selecting the LVM option during the installation process. I have now managed to install and run several distros and have settled on Kubuntu 18.04.

Hope that it helps.

DJH

Comment: Hi, I tried the installation process with LVM option today. Unfortunately it doesn't work for me. The installation process freeze again when trying to install grub2.