# Dual Boot in legacy mode, unable to boot into windows 10

Tags: dual-boot, 18.04

Recently I installed Ubuntu 18.04 alongside with windows 10. Now i'm facing few problems. I had Ubuntu 18.04 installed before. Then i decided to install windows 10. I wanted a fresh start. So i deleted all my partitions and Then created new partition for windows and installed windows 10 in legacy mode. Then i created partition for Ubuntu and installed Ubuntu 18.04 in legacy mode. Then i got `System Bootorder not found` this error, and solved it from [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/862946/unable-to-install-ubuntu-on-acer-aspire-es1-533/876153#876153). Now the problems are:

- While starting i see blank screen for 30+ seconds.
- It directly boot me into Ubuntu 18.04

Can anyone help me to solve the blank screen problem and how to boot into windows 10/showing boot options?

Boot Info Script 8f991e4 + Boot-Repair extra info      [Boot-Info 25oct2017]

=============================Boot Info Summary:===============================

=> Grub2 (v2.00) is installed in the MBR of /dev/sda and looks at sector 1 of 
    the same hard drive for core.img. core.img is at this location and looks 
    for (,msdos8)/boot/grub. It also embeds following components:

```
modules
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
fshelp ext2 part_msdos biosdisk
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

sda1: __________________________________________________________________________

```
File system:       ntfs
Boot sector type:  Windows 8/2012: NTFS
Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
Operating System:  
Boot files:        /bootmgr /Boot/BCD
```

sda2: __________________________________________________________________________

```
File system:       ntfs
Boot sector type:  Windows 8/2012: NTFS
Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
Operating System:  
Boot files:        /bootmgr /Windows/System32/winload.exe
```

sda3: __________________________________________________________________________

```
File system:       
Boot sector type:  -
Boot sector info: 
Mounting failed:   mount: /mnt/BootInfo/sda3: unknown filesystem type ''.
```

sda4: __________________________________________________________________________

```
File system:       Extended Partition
Boot sector type:  -
Boot sector info:
```

sda5: __________________________________________________________________________

```
File system:       swap
Boot sector type:  -
Boot sector info:
```

sda6: __________________________________________________________________________

```
File system:       vfat
Boot sector type:  FAT32
Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
Operating System:  
Boot files:        /EFI/ubuntu/grub.cfg /EFI/BOOT/fbx64.efi 
                   /EFI/BOOT/fwupx64.efi /EFI/BOOT/grubx64.efi 
                   /EFI/BOOT/mmx64.efi /EFI/BOOT/shimx64.efi 
                   /EFI/ubuntu/fwupx64.efi /EFI/ubuntu/grubx64.efi 
                   /EFI/ubuntu/mmx64.efi /EFI/ubuntu/shimx64.efi
```

sda7: __________________________________________________________________________

```
File system:       ext4
Boot sector type:  -
Boot sector info: 
Operating System:  
Boot files:
```

sda8: __________________________________________________________________________

```
File system:       ext4
Boot sector type:  -
Boot sector info: 
Operating System:  Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS
Boot files:        /boot/grub/grub.cfg /etc/fstab 
                   /boot/grub/i386-pc/core.img
```

============================ Drive/Partition Info:=============================

```
Drive: sda _____________________________________________________________________
Disk /dev/sda: 931.5 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos

Partition  Boot  Start Sector    End Sector  # of Sectors  Id System

/dev/sda1               2,048     1,026,047     1,024,000   7 NTFS / exFAT / HPFS
/dev/sda2           1,026,048   419,432,447   418,406,400   7 NTFS / exFAT / HPFS
/dev/sda3         419,432,448 1,033,832,447   614,400,000   6 FAT16
/dev/sda4       1,033,834,494 1,953,523,711   919,689,218   5 Extended
/dev/sda5       1,033,834,496 1,065,832,447    31,997,952  82 Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda6    *  1,065,834,496 1,069,832,191     3,997,696  ef EFI (FAT-12/16/32)
/dev/sda7       1,069,834,240 1,558,114,303   488,280,064  83 Linux
/dev/sda8       1,558,116,352 1,953,523,711   395,407,360  83 Linux
```

//skipped other logs//

```
grub-install --version
grub-install (GRUB) 2.02-2ubuntu8.2,grub-install (GRUB) 2.

Reinstall the GRUB of sda8 into the MBR of sda
Installing for i386-pc platform.
Installation finished. No error reported.
grub-install /dev/sda: exit code of grub-install /dev/sda:0

update-grub
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-33-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-33-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-32-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-32-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-29-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-29-generic
Adding boot menu entry for EFI firmware configuration
Windows is hibernated, refused to mount.
The disk contains an unclean file system (0, 0).
Metadata kept in Windows cache, refused to mount.
Falling back to read-only mount because the NTFS partition is in an
unsafe state. Please resume and shutdown Windows fully (no hibernation
or fast restarting.)
NTFS signature is missing.
Failed to mount '/dev/sda3': Invalid argument
The device '/dev/sda3' doesn't seem to have a valid NTFS.
Maybe the wrong device is used? Or the whole disk instead of a
partition (e.g. /dev/sda, not /dev/sda1)? Or the other way around?
mount /dev/sda3 : Error code 12
mount -r /dev/sda3 /mnt/boot-sav/sda3
NTFS signature is missing.
Failed to mount '/dev/sda3': Invalid argument
The device '/dev/sda3' doesn't seem to have a valid NTFS.
Maybe the wrong device is used? Or the whole disk instead of a
partition (e.g. /dev/sda, not /dev/sda1)? Or the other way around?
mount -r /dev/sda3 : Error code 12
Unhide GRUB boot menu in sda8/boot/grub/grub.cfg

Boot successfully repaired.

You can now reboot your computer.
```

The boot files of [The OS now in use - Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS] are far from the start of the disk. Your BIOS may not detect them. You may want to retry after creating a /boot partition (EXT4, >200MB, start of the disk). This can be performed via tools such as gParted. Then select this partition via the [Separate /boot partition:] option of [Boot Repair]. (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootPartition)

Comment: When in Ubuntu, if you run `sudo os-prober` from a terminal window, does it return your Windows installation?

Comment: Its now showing anything.

Comment: It sounds like the bootloader for Windows needs to be fixed.  Maybe try [Boot Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) and see if that helps.

Comment: I just used boot-repair. from the log i just copy those portion. Which is seems important about dual boot.
update-grub
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-33-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-33-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-32-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-32-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-29-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-29-generic
Adding boot menu entry for EFI firmware configuration
Windows is hibernated, refused to mount.

Comment: Can you please edit your question and add that you just put here there so that others can see it?  I don't know if Windows being hibernated can be fixed from Ubuntu or not without losing data.  I know that there are answers here on how to get rid of the hiberfile.sys from Windows, but again, that might cause data loss.

Comment: Updated the questions.

Comment: Good!  Gave you an upvote for visual.  Hopefully someone with a little more experience than me might know what to do to help.  =)

Comment: Looks like your Windows is hibernated. You say you installed in legacy mode, but then you used an answer which is valid for UEFI-mode to reinstall Grub. But that should be ok now, boot-repair reinstalled correct Grub version already. You only need to disable `fast startup` in Windows.

Comment: how do i do that? @mook765

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/970931/how-to-prevent-against-windows-10-being-unable-to-boot-dual-boot-win10-deb-stab/970937#970937

Comment: @mook765 i can't even boot into windows 10. So how am i gonna able to do that?

Comment: @AlauddinAhmed Oh, sorry, I didn't think about that you are not able to boot Windows. I don't know how to do it then.