# Reinstalling correct grub package to Acer device 18.04

Tags: boot, grub2, uefi, 64-bit

After installing ubuntu to my machine (Acer Aspire F5-572G), UEFI is unable to detect grub as the boot manager. The closest answer to fixing this is [Unable to install Ubuntu on Acer Aspire ES1-533](https://askubuntu.com/questions/862946/unable-to-install-ubuntu-on-acer-aspire-es1-533).

The issue is that this solution above proposess `sudo apt-get install --reinstall grub-efi-amd64`. However my machine is of Intel 64 bit architecture.. and not AMD.. When preforming `apt-cache search grub-efi` it provides the possible packages:

```
grub-efi
grub-efi-amd64
grub-efi-amd64-bin
grub-efi-amd64-dbg
grub-efi-amd64-signed
grub-efi-ia32
grub-efi-ia32-bin
grub-efi-ia32-dbg
```

Since my computer is Intel 64-bit arch, I'm not completely sure of the consequences either installing a ia32 or amd64...

### Hence I am wanting to know:

- Would amd64 bit work?
- Is there any risk to choosing ia32 with 64 bit archeture?
- Any other possible method of getting grub noticed by UEFI?

Note: I have wiped hard disk recently and able to reinstall ubuntu to hard drive if anything breaks :)

Cheers

Comment: AMD64 is correct for all 64 bit systems

Comment: Acer needs UEFI update, if not most current. Also if SSD, you should update SSD firmware. All Acer need "trust" setting in UEFI. Acer Aspire E15 will not dual boot, many details Trust settings in step 35
http://askubuntu.com/questions/627416/acer-aspire-e15-will-not-dual-boot
 & https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2297947 & 
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2358003

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you installed the 64 bit ISO:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall grub-efi-amd64
```

If you installed the 32 bit ISO:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall grub-efi
```

Theoretically 32 bit apps should run fine on 64 bit architecture, but will only run at 32 bit speed.

You may also want to look into running [Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair).

Comment: Was able to solve without boot repair. Thank you for the help!