# Ubuntu Live usb not able to boot

Tags: boot, virtualbox, uefi, live-usb, msi

I installed ubuntu 18.04 on a live usb drive under UEFI mode by using Virtualbox.

It works fine, I'm able to boot on virtualbox from the usb drive.

But when I tried to boot from the usb drive on my actual laptop, my laptop keep showing "system BootOrder not found, Initializing defaults" and then restart.
To solve this problem I followed the solution under this post [Unable to install Ubuntu on Acer Aspire ES1-533](https://askubuntu.com/questions/862946/unable-to-install-ubuntu-on-acer-aspire-es1-533/876153#876153) on virtual machine and tried to boot from usb again.

This time, the bios is showing "Invalid signature detected. Check secure Boot Policy in Setup". And I'm not able to boot into ubuntu using virtualbox neither, the it just keep showing the grub prompt.

I'm using a MSI laptop. Inside BIOS I don't have option to make custom boot or add secure key.

I'm going to reinstall the ubuntu onto the usb drive using virtualbox. What should I do to solve boot problem? Thank you.

Comment: Have you updated UEFI? And turned UEFI Secure Boot off. Are drives set to AHCI? Can you run this? Lets see details, use ppa version with your live installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not  Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: Yes, the ubuntu is able to boot when I change UEFI to legacy mode with secure boot off. But this also cause windows not boot up when I want to switch back since it's OEM system. All drives are set to AHCI.

Comment: Which Ubuntu 18.04 ISO are you trying to use? The latest or an earlier one? Did you verify the ISO as being valid, then then the write to your thumb-drive?  https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu#0 and https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/CDIntegrityCheck

Comment: I believe it's the latest ISO from ubuntu website https://releases.ubuntu.com/18.04.5/

Comment: Why do you need to use VirtualBox at all instead of installing Ubuntu directly in UEFI mode on the USB drive with VirtualBox? It would remove the error.

Answer (score 0):

So you are saying that you install Ubuntu and windows on your laptop but now you can't switch to window ... I mean your system make ubuntu as default system ...
try this
go into boot menu and check if there is window option is showing or not ... if yes then let me know about it then I will give you rest solution or you can find it by searching how to change default system on dual boot

Comment: What I’m trying to do is create a Live USB Linux so I can use it on any computer. But my laptop’s secure boot is preventing boot from usb device. But if I turn off he secure boot, my OEM windows will not boot. Which means  I have to go into bios every time I changed system which is annoying. Therefore I’m looking for a way to bypass the secure boot.

Comment: Windows should boot with Secure boot off or on, but only in UEFI boot mode, not legacy/CSM/BIOS mode. Many UEFI systems also have a separate setting to allow USB boot or full USB support. Secure systems do not allow USB boot as then its not secure. Not sure you you ever repair a fully locked down system, but maybe that is intent.

Comment: ok I got it now let's check some BIOS setting  ...1.go in advance boot option and then enable the legacy option from ..don't forget to turn off secure boot... and then check  also check for USB configuration enable both options...it's work for me I hope it will work for you