# Ubuntu 18.04 + LUKS + LVM. System boots only after hard reset

Tags: boot, xubuntu, lvm, luks, 18.04

Today I dowloaded xUbuntu 18.04 amd64 Desktop and I decided to install it on my Lenovo ideapad 310 using LUKS encryption and LVM (I never installed Ubuntu before in this configuration).

I have configured LUKS and installed xUbuntu strictly according to this manual:

[Installing Kubuntu 16.04 with LVM+LUKS full encryption](https://www.unmanarc.com/v1/2017/07/installing-k-ubuntu-16-04-with-lvmluks-full-encryption/) except the only thing that I didn't have `/dev/sda3` and `/dev/sda4` partitions before setup.

After I did it all I met a strange bug. Every time I turn my laptop off through the system menu and then turn on, the OS asks me for LUKS password, I enter it and then Xubuntu freezes:

[image: screenshot]

Nothing helps: neither <kbd>Esc</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Fn</kbd> nor <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd>. When I power it off and then power on, xUbuntu boots well - no errors and no freezes. But when I turned it off thru the system menu again, it freezes again on next boot. And so on.

I'm not professional at Linux so I don't know what to do in this case and what logs to analyze. So, please, help me.

Here's my `/etc/fstab` (I removed almost all comments):

```
/dev/mapper/vg0-root / ext4 errors=remount-ro 0 1
# /boot was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=b76851f2-1cd6-4fff-8fb9-1d57a637e8a4 /boot ext4 defaults 0 2
/dev/mapper/vg0-home /home ext4 defaults 0 2
/dev/mapper/vg0-swap none swap sw 0 0
```

and here's my `/etc/crypttab`:

```
hdcrypt0 UUID=f0bb4293-c7d7-405c-9926-49553be1369c none luks,discard
```

**UPDATE #1**

I reinstalled xUbuntu and tried [this manual](https://askubuntu.com/a/893906/822711), but xUbuntu still freezes after accepting LUKS password.

What log files should I check to find out what's the problem?

**UPDATE #2**

`nomodeset` also doesn't help.

**UPDATE #3**

After I spent so much time trying to get my laptop work with encrypted hard disk, I didn't find a solution. I installed Debian Stretch on encrypted disk and it works well but Debian is not the OS I'd like to have as a desktop. Linux Mint also works great, I think I'll migrate to it later.

Comment: Please try according to this link, [Install (entire disk with lvm and encryption) in Xubuntu Desktop amd64 in Bionic Daily](http://iso.qa.ubuntu.com/qatracker/milestones/389/builds/171119/testcases/1451/results). It is designed for *Xubuntu*.

Comment: Thank you for the link, but this manual is for automatic configuring. I don't want to encrypt the whole disk, only a half. I want to install Kali on the second half of disk later, when I'm done with xUbuntu.

Comment: Maybe the problem is not lvm with encryption, but something else for example problems with the hardware driver for your *graphics chip/card or wifi chip/card. Please specify the brand name and model of those.* You could try to install Xubuntu without encryption first, and when it works, overwrite it with the final system that you want (lvm and LUKS encryption in part of the drive).

Comment: Yes, it seems like hardware problem. Laptop is Lenovo ideapad 310-15ISK with NVIDIA GeForce 920MX videocard.

Comment: What do you mean by "overwrite it with the final system"?

Comment: Actually I tried to install proprietary Nvidia drivers, but still no result.

Comment: The [boot option](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2230389&p=13370808#post13370808) `nomodeset` will often help with nvidia graphics to get it going.

Comment: "overwrite it with the final system" alias "use the same drive space, partition(s)"

Comment: If you start your comment with @sudodus, I will be notified automatically. Otherwise I might not find your comment.

Comment: @sudodus Well I tried so many things these days but nothing helped.  1. Tried to install without encryption - it worked well, but after overwriting still freezes. 2. Tried to use automatic full encryption - you advised it in your first message - still freezes. 3. Tried to do the same steps installing 16.04 - no result, still freezes with encryption. 4. Tried to install dkms and update intel microcode (don't know exactly what for) - no changes.

Comment: @sudodus I removed quiet and splash from grub's GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT to see what's happening while booting and I saw that laptop hangs in two situations: [see screenshots](https://imgur.com/a/8S4JaGg). But I don't know if it will help

Comment: I think your problem is the nvidia card - to make the linux driver work with it. When your live session (booted from USB) works, it *should* be possible to make the installed system work. Have you used the boot option `nomodeset` also with the installed system? If still no luck, try another version of Xubuntu (18.04 LTS, 16.04.1 LTS, 16.04.4 LTS all have different linux kernels and different versions of the linux drivers).

Comment: According to your pictures, 'RF Kill Switch ...', there could also be a problem with the linux driver for the WiFi card. I don't know much about that, but other people here know a lot. It is a good idea to start another thread *alias ask another question* to focus on the wifi driver issue and make those people interested.

Comment: @sudodus I'm curiuos why it should be nvidia card or wifi problem. Before trying to use encryption I had been working with this laptop having installed xUbuntu 16.04 for a year or so and there were no such freezes at all. This problem appeared only when I started to use encryption. As I mentioned above even 16.04 which worked perfectly before, started to hang with enabled encryption.

Comment: 1. 'NVIDIA GeForce 920MX videocard' ; 2. 'RF Kill Switch ...' -- But I don't know. I am only guessing based on the information that you have given.

Comment: @sudodus For now I didn't find a solution - just written an UPDATE #3. Well anyway thank you so much for the time you spent on it!

Comment: You are welcome. Sorry that I could not help you find a working solution with Ubuntu :-( But I am glad that you have found solutions with other linux distros :-)