# How to partition Ubuntu to span multiple disks?

Tags: server, partitioning, system-installation

How can you go about partitioning Ubuntu so that it spans multiple disks during the installation process of Ubuntu Server 15.10? Is it even possible to do this?

Comment: You would need to decide which directories lived on which drive.  This can easily be set up during installation.  Another option would be LVM.

Comment: Do you mean a RAID like setup, or just separate / and home?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the proper way to install Ubuntu 15.04 with LVM, LUKS, and manual partitioning?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/663332/what-is-the-proper-way-to-install-ubuntu-15-04-with-lvm-luks-and-manual-partit)

Comment: It's fairly obvious to me this is an installation script question. It is also fairly obvious the OP wants to abstract a number of physical disks as a single logical volume during the install, say to effect /dev/sdnn as a mountpoint for / as an 40TB SCSI device with 4 10TB HDD's. What is the issue with comprehending this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Logical Volume Manager](https://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/Deployment_Guide-en-US/ch-lvm.html)(LVM) for this. I have a detailed [thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/728174/using-lvm-in-the-already-running-ubuntu-system) which talks about this topic. It has some other pointers(references) also.

In general the OOTB Ubuntu creates two partitions for you - root(/) and swap.

But you would like to have /usr, /opt, /home, /var on different logical volumes which can span across the disks(and giving you flexibility to add the disk to the logical group/volume later if needed).

Comment: This is typically done for /var to get it off SSD, and for where a stack of HDD's is required for MySQL.  Setting up LVM to span a bunch of disks should be possibly during install. The question is about the install script, not about merging later. It's a moot point for 15.05 arguably, but should apply to any LTS release.