# How to change the default partitioning scheme during install (partman config)?

Tags: partitioning, system-installation, encryption

Last time I was installing Ubuntu, I ran it live from usb and changed the `partman`'s config for the default partitioning scheme.

That was the easiest way to get full disk encryption, yet have the custom partition sizes (larger `boot`, no `swap`). The alternative would be using gparted and manually configuring LUKS, a far cry from simply ticking "encrypt" setting at the install (see https://askubuntu.com/a/918030/47073 for the stupid amount of steps required).

Unfortunately I forgot where the `partman`'s config is with the default partitioning scheme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have figured this out while installing.

The configurations are in `/lib/partman/recipes*`, e.g. `/lib/partman/recipes-amd64-efi/`. For me, editing the `30atomic` file did the trick.

See https://askubuntu.com/a/678074/47073 for the details of editing.